# LINQ where int equals many results

Tags: c#, linq

I have a statement that reads

```
ID == repository.Where(x => x.Value == "1" || x.Value == "2")
                .Select( x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will result in 2 `ID`s, lets say, 1 and 2, therefore using `FirstOrDefault()` is incorrect as `ID` may equal the other value which isn't first.

Using `linq`(and preferably not a `foreach` loop) how can I say if the `ID` equals any of the results that come from the `linq` query?

---

**EDIT** - No one seems to understand what I am asking. Therefore I will explain a bit of what the above is doing and say why this is causing my problem, and then how the answer I marked below helps me before it is closed.

Basically, the FirstOrDefault() will return **ONE** value from one of the where clause values. (Which is the desired affect) - However, as there is an OR condition, it will bring back **twos** IDs which means there is a 50/50 chance that the outer condition (the one what I say ID == linq query) could be true.

So the solution is too remove the `FirstOrDefault()` as remember, this returns **ONE** value and replace it with `Any()` which basically means if my ID matches ANY of the returned IDs from the linq query result, then the outer condition is true. Please look at my answer.

---

Comment: You need to look up `Enumerable.Contains`

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? Maybe you state the "equivalent" foreach loop?

Comment: Why question the question and down mark when there are two perfectly good answers that was posted before the down mark and the above comment? crazy

Comment: @user3428422 because the question still makes no sense. The goal of this site is to help all programmers, not just *you*, questions should be written in a clear manner to help future visitors.

Comment: I still state there were 2 pretty quick answers to the question above, and yes, it will help others regardless as the syntax is pretty self-explanatory. I cannot state a question that would be understood to all levels of programmers. But I will consider your comments for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your sequence:

```
repository
  .Where(x => x.Value == "1" || x.Value == "2")
  .Select( x => x.Id)
```

You can use `.Any()` on that sequence to determine if any item therein matches a given condition:

```
repository
  .Where(x => x.Value == "1" || x.Value == "2")
  .Select( x => x.Id)
  .Any(x => x == ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Contains` method

```
repository
 .Where(x => x.Value == "1" || x.Value == "2")
 .Select(x =>x.Id)
 .Contains(ID)
```